# XCode - Working with Build > Analyze, Potential Leak Warnings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

I just discovered the Build > Analyze feature of XCode today so I am trying to go through and address all the errors it is finding. There are a few lines XCode finds exception with that are confusing me:

```
    //Test View
    self.imageViewTest = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.imageViewTest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); // <=== Leak
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageViewTest];
    //Test View 2
    self.imageViewTestB = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.imageViewTestB.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100); // <=== Leak
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageViewTestB];
```

and later in my setup of video capture

```
    self.captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES; // <=== Leak
```

The warning at each of these lines is "Potential leak of an object". All 3 of these objects are sent the `release` message in my `dealloc` method. What could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: How are each of these properties declared (retain, assign, copy, etc)?

Comment: They are all declared as retain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using ARC and your properties are setup with the retain attribute, then yes, these are leaks. This line:

```
self.imageViewTest = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

should be:

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.imageViewTest = iv;
[iv release];
```

or:

```
self.imageViewTest = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or better yet, use ARC. It makes things SO much easier.

Comment: Oh ok cool. Yea this project was well along before ARC came out last year and I have been intimidated by trying to convert it to use ARC. Is it very involved to transition to use ARC?

Comment: Depends on the code. I converted a project with over 400 non-trivial .m files this summer. It took me about two hours to convert. Most projects will be much easier.

Comment: That's not bad. Is there a well made tutorial out there to follow to save myself some headaches?